# Run Application in background

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, desktop-application

What is the best way to run an eclipse RPC application in background? I want to run an application without user awareness, doing some processes and closing application. 
Is it possible to run it without displaying UI?
Should I create a new product?

Comment: Yes. Application without UI is possible.You can create a runnable Jar of your application and it is double-clickable.

Comment: Search for 'eclipse headless application'

Comment: Why do you want to run a Rich Client application without a GUI?